# Show span element when mouseover parent span

Tags: html, css

When I mouseover a `span.label` element I want to show a children `span.dM` element. Which is perfectly happening in the fiddle below.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/rVLpq/)

What I am trying to achieve is when I hover in the place of where `span.dM` appears then I should get a gray background for `span.label`. Currently I have to hover on the text "some text" to see the `span.dM` element.

I want to fix this without using any width. Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/rVLpq/1/

Comment: not exactly, I do not want to stretch the `span.label` element. It should finish where `span.dM` finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot hover over a `display:none`. 
If it's possible, hide the span with `visibility:hidden`.
This way the element isn't removed from the document flow, and you can hover on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/z4JBG/

Answer (score 0):

I've forked your jsfiddle, using jquery to achieve the effect you were after.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrxGf/

Comment: The effect is same as mine. You are using jquery to achieve the same effect as I have. But I want to mouseover in the place of span.dM to appear it.